# Unity MenuItem Fading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want the MenuItem to be transparent
But it completely disappears from the list of items.

The script I used:

```
using UnityEditor;

public class Example 
{
    static bool showMenu = false;
    [MenuItem("GameObject/MY/Test", true)]
    private static bool CreateEmpityMap() { return showMenu; }
    [MenuItem("GameObject/MY/Test", false)]
    private static void CreateEmpityMap(MenuCommand menuCommand)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Unity version: **2022.2.20**

The Current result:

[image]

The desired result:

[image]

Comment: The menu name in the script is "GameObject/MY/Create Empity Map", but what is shown in the picture is "My Custom Menu". Is there any connection between them?

Comment: The image in question is an example.
And I did not create it.

Comment: @MeysamGhorbani how about you show us your actual menu then? ;) currently it is a bit unclear what the issue is

Comment: Just tried and can not reproduce this ... copied your exact code into an empty script and the button shows up as disabled under the `GameObject` menu https://imgur.com/nqMcKUu ... you will get an error log though if there is no tag `Map` defined for your project ...

Comment: MY menu does not appear for me.
Are you using Unity version 2022.2.20?